# Firebase: Android : How to show list of contacts who have the app Installed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Google auth via firebase and am logging the users in successfully. I also have retrieved the list of contacts from the phonebook (device) and displaying it on a listview in a fragment in my app. But now I wish to show the users amongst my contacts **who have my app installed**, so that when clicked on they will go to the private chat with them, the other contacts, when clicked on will enable them to send an app invite. In a nutshell: I want to view the list of contacts who have the app installed on their device.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and what problem you are facing.

Comment: How are you indicating, in your contact list, who has the app installed and who doesn't? i.e. if I looked at all your contacts, what would tell me that a contact has the app installed?

Comment: Have you solved it? I can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this in three straightforward steps.

- Get a list of your phone contacts
- Get a list of all the phone numbers on Firestore
- Compare the two lists and return common elements.

In order to use my approach, you need to have a collection on Firestore that has the phone number of all your users as documents just like the image below:

[image]

Here are the steps:

**Step 1:** I got a list of all the user's contacts by using ContentResolver. You can use the method below to retrieve this list provided you have the `READ_CONTACTS` permission granted.

```
public ArrayList<String> getContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    // list to be returned
    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    // cursor
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {

        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {

            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {

                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + name);
                    numbers.add(formatRightWay(phoneNo));
                }

                pCur.close();
            }
          }
        }

        if(cur!=null){
            cur.close();
          }

        return numbers;
}
```

**Step 2:** I got a list of all the phone numbers on Firestore by fetching the document IDs of the `user` collection. Here's a quick implementation:

```
firestore.collection("users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            list.add(document.getId());
        }
        // this is the list you need
        Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
    }
  }
});
```

**Step 3:** Write a method that compares the two lists and returns similar elements.

```
public static ArrayList<String> shuffleBothLists(ArrayList<String> phoneContacts, List<String> firebaseContacts) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String s: firebaseContacts) {
        if(phoneContacts.contains(s) && !result.contains(s)) {
            result.add(s);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The list returned by the method above are your contacts that have the app installed.

Cheers!

Comment: It's possible some numbers won't have country code to match to correctly to your firebase users.

Comment: @LearnToday, in that case, you should have a fixed phone number format for your project. Validate and make sure the user's phone number conforms to your format **at the point of signup** and also **at the point of querying**.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to list the contacts directly. You need to create one node for users in firebase database to store users details after registration and then you can retrieve those user details.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting you in means that you are using firebase. Now you want to upload all contacts to your server in firebase databse by your app if installed in one's device.

Try below code:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressDialog dialog;
DatabaseReference yourReference;//your database reference

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    yourReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_your);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Uploading contacts...");

// Query for contacts through content resolver. You will get a cursor.
    Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
            },
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

// If you have a list as your data, firebase facilitates you to upload that easily by a single HashMap object. Create a HashMap object.

    HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

// Loop contacts cursor with map to put all contacts in map. I used contact name as key and number as its value (simple and pretty way).
    if(contacts!=null) {
        while(contacts.moveToNext()){
            map.put(
                    contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)),
                    contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
            );
        }
        contacts.close();
    }

    dialog.show();
//write map to firebase database reference...
    yourReference.updateChildren(map)
//this onSuccessListener is optional. You can terminate above line of code by ";" (semicolon).
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Contacts uploaded suffessfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
//this onFailureListener is also optional.
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.w("MKN","Error: "+e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Contacts upload failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

You will need to provide READ_CONTACTS permission to query Contacts table.
Also in firebase rules, value for "write" key must be "true" to write to the database.

Answer (score 0):

First retrieve the contact list ..

```
    'ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) {
                    //to get the contact names
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                    if( email != null ){
                        map.put("name", name);
                        map.put("email", email);
                        getContactList.add(map);
                    }
                }
                cur1.close();
            }
        }'
```

After this you can maintain a firebase database table that can store authenticated user's information, you can sync your contacts with the list you fetch from firebase user's database.

```
    'mapChat = new HashMap<>();
        Log.d("Debug", clist.toString());
        userReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        userReference1.keepSynced(true);
        userReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (int x = 0; x < clist.size(); x++) {
                    //Log.d("Debug" ,list.get(x).get("email").toString());

                    for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        if (dsp.hasChild("email")) {

                            //    Log.d("Debug" , "setnewuser "  + dsp.child("email").getValue().toString());
                            if (dsp.child("email").getValue().toString().equals(clist.get(x).get("email").toString())) {
                                Log.d("Debug", "contact updated");
                                String uid = dsp.getKey().toString();
                                reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(id).child("contacts").child(uid);

                                mapChat.put("name", clist.get(x).get("name"));
                                mapChat.put("email", clist.get(x).get("email"));
                                mapChat.put("chats", "false");
                                reference1.setValue(mapChat);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                reference1.onDisconnect();
                contactIdInterface1.contactUpdated();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });'
```

Comment: How would you propose to *retrieve the Firebase Authentication user's list*? Do you have some code example that would provide a solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't provide a solution as some contacts have the app installed and some don't - there's no flag to idicate which is which. It also doesn't provide a way, when clicked, to go to a private chat room.

Comment: @Jay this method works, i have used it for my chat application, definitely we need to maintain the chats database in firebase so that each contact in the list can be provided a chat room.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's working code, but it's not a solution to the question. The OP wants a solution that *show the users amongst my contacts who have my app installed*. He doesn't want to copy his contacts to Firebase which is what the code in solution mostly does, he wants a solution to keep track of who has his app installed.

Answer (score -1):

Enable and Implement Phone number sign in  method in firebase, so u can retrieve the contacts from firebase and compare it will local contact list after that its easy to implement ur logic